# Using JOIN to avoid SELECT-in-SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Say I have a database table with the following structure

Table **record**:

```
id       INT NOT NULL (PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT)
parent   INT NOT NULL
priority INT NUL NULL
```

Now I want to select all the records, but I need a column that matches each row to the subsequent (based on `priority`, ascending order) that has the same `parent` - if it exists, otherwise `NULL`. In this arbitrary example, `parent` is an identifer to a completely external table and has nothing to do with the records directly.

For example thedataset:

```
| id | parent | priority |
|----|--------|----------|
| 1  | 1      | 2        |
| 2  | 1      | 6        |
| 3  | 1      | 1        |
| 4  | 2      | 4        |
| 5  | 2      | 3        |
```

Should produce the following:

```
| id | parent | priority | match |
|----|--------|----------|-------|
| 1  | 1      | 2        | 2     |
| 2  | 1      | 6        | NULL  |
| 3  | 1      | 1        | 1     |
| 4  | 2      | 4        | NULL  |
| 5  | 2      | 3        | 4     |
```

An SQL implementation that works is:

```
SELECT r1.*, 
    (SELECT r2.id 
        FROM record AS r2 
        WHERE r2.parent = r1.parent 
            AND r2.priority > r1.priority 
        ORDER BY r2.priority ASC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS match_id
FROM record AS r1
```

However, I'm quite concerned with the SELECT-in-SELECT with regards to scalability. Any ideas of how to do this cleanly? Is it possible to do using JOINs?

Comment: how does 1 match 2 but 2 doesn't match 1? and how does 3 match 1?? and how does 4 doesn't match anyone but 1 matches 2? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: ok nvm I got it, depends on the priority.

Comment: I got pretty confused too even though it is explicitly stated that parent is an external table with no relation with id :D

Comment: Yes, it's not that clear that you want to pull corresponding row `id` based on `priority` match. I got the idea by reading your query. It would be better if you rephrased your description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have unique priority for each parent  I believe this would work:

```
select r.id, r.parent, r.priority, r2.id as `match`
from (
    select r.id, r.parent, r.priority, min(r2.priority) as next_priority
    from record r
    left join record r2 on
      r.parent = r2.parent
      and r.priority < r2.priority
    group by r.id, r.parent, r.priority
  ) r
left join record r2 on
    r.parent = r2.parent
    and r.next_priority = r2.priority
order by r.id
```

`match` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, so backticks are required.

How this works is we pull next priority from ascending order which is higher than current one and based on that (and the fact that we have unique priorities for each parent) we can pull corresponding row id.

[**Live DEMO - SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78d9e5/1)

Comment: Right. So this will perform effectively 2 queries by using SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) as opposed to N queries by SELECT (SELECT ...) FROM. Correctly understood?

Comment: I believe that's correct. Your solution evaluates for each row which hurts performance. The more rows you store, the slower it will execute. I'd bet that it's slower than the one I'm proposing, even if you may get different results within small tables (not a lot of data).

Comment: Yes. I like this solution. I've never done SELECT .. FROM (SELECT ...) before. It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This WILL work for you here and avoid the use of subqueries as you mentioned. Youre able to do what you want with a `LEFT` join so the nulls will stay and then putting what you want on the `on` such as `r1.parent = r2.parent and r2.priority > r1.priority`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a592/25

```
SELECT r1.*, r2.id as 'Match'
FROM record r1
left join record r2 on r1.parent = r2.parent and r2.priority > r1.priority
group by r1.id
```

Comment: I am really curious how mysql do r1.* after group by by r1.id. It is worked but how? Alle other databases produce errors here ;-)

Comment: I see that this provides the correct result, but how do I know for sure it will select the first r2 when multiple verify the join criteria? E.g. if you remove the group by, id 3 will match with 1, and 2.

Comment: Exactly, MySQL let's you get away with grouping by not all the columns, but then it pulls arbitrary row which other modern databases don't allow.